# Tomcat Manager - Active Directory Authentication

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, ldap

I want to know how it's possible to use Active directory, for access roles on tomcat manager app?

The idea is to make possible accees to http://localhost:8080/manager application for specific LDAP Group.

I browsed the net, but ahven't find a complete solution.

Best regards

Comment: You use the LDAP plugin. Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution;
I had created a JNDIRealm t ask my AD for authentication

```
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
             debug="99"
             connectionURL="ldap://LDAPSERVER:PORT"
             connectionName="LDAP_USER"
             connectionPassword="LDAP_PWD" 
             adcompat="true"
             referrals="follow"
             userBase="OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com" 
             userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
             userSubtree="true"
             userRoleName="memberOf"
             roleBase="OU=Groups,DC=company,DC=com"
             roleName="cn" 
             roleSearch="(member={0})" 
             roleSubtree="true"
             roleNested="true"
             authentication="simple"
             />
    </Realm>
```

Then, I modified the web.xml of my tomcat Manager application, the idea is to add the desired AD Group that should have access to the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <display-name>Tomcat Manager Application</display-name>
  <description>
    A scriptable management web application for the Tomcat Web Server;
    Manager lets you view, load/unload/etc particular web applications.
  </description>

  <request-character-encoding>UTF-8</request-character-encoding>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Manager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HTMLManager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- Uncomment this to show proxy sessions from the Backup manager or a
         StoreManager in the sessions list for an application
    <init-param>
      <param-name>showProxySessions</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <multipart-config>
      <!-- 50MB max -->
      <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Status</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.manager.StatusManagerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JMXProxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.manager.JMXProxyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Define the Manager Servlet Mapping -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Manager</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/text/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Status</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/status/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JMXProxy</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/jmxproxy/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HTMLManager</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/html/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>CSRF</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
      <param-value>/html,/html/,/html/list,/index.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRF</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>HTMLManager</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- Define a Security Constraint on this Application -->
  <!-- NOTE:  None of these roles are present in the default users file -->
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>HTML Manager interface (for humans)</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/html/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>
       <role-name>MY_AUTHORIZED_AD_GROUP</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
   <login-config>
       <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
   </login-config>

  <!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
  <security-role>
    <description>
      The role that is required to access the HTML Manager pages
    </description>
    <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <description>
      The role that is required to access to the Manager Status pages
    </description>
    <role-name>MY_AUTHORIZED_AD_GROUP</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role-ref>
    <role-name>manager-gui</role-name>
    <role-link>MY_AUTHORIZED_AD_GROUP</role-link>
  </security-role-ref>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/403.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to update the following line in the config to get the status page to also load.

```
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTML Manager interface (for humans)</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/html/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/status/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
```