# Is basic Auth the only way to login to Apache Tomcat manager?

Tags: basic-authentication, tomcat8

I always read that basic authentication is unsecure. Still on the apache tomcat doc https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html it is described how to login using basic auth. Is there another way to implement the login to the manager?

Comment: Basic authentication through an encrypted channel is secure. Nowadays the easiest solution is to configure TLS **and** use basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other methods for authentication with tomcat manager.
Example here: [Tomcat Manager - Active Directory Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64283665/3410989)

I also remember doing this once using [Waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle). Discussed here for instance: https://code.dblock.org/2010/11/30/waffle-configuring-tomcats-manager-application.html